# How to use "Function Mapping" in Tera Data?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Who can show me some examples of using "CREATE FUNCTION MAPPING" in Tera data?
(Don't use READ_NOS example， I want to know other "CREATE FUNCTION MAPPING" application situation)

```
CREATE FUNCTION MAPPING READ_NOS_json_fm
  FOR READ_NOS
  EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER TRUSTED DefAuth
  USING
    LOCATION('/S3/td-usgs.s3.amazonaws.com/JSONDATA'),
  RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_RECORD') ;
```

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/UG7kfQnbU2ZiX41~Mu75kQ/HViL9kSPmFyXZkRAsPpNgg) for examples?

Comment: Thanks.  But  a lot of info.  Not easy to understand.

Comment: In essence it lets you create an alias for a table operator / table function and supply some defaults so those parameters / options don't have to be specified explicitly in every query.

Comment: ok  Thanks  . Answer me and I 'll chose you as the correct answer . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, a `FUNCTION MAPPING` allows you to create an alias for a table operator or table function, and to supply some defaults for parameters and options. Then those do not have to be specified explicitly in every query.